# Анимация. Не плавное вращение

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть картинка (индикатор загрузки). Картинка подразумевает вращение на определенное количество градусов за такт (не плавное). Как это можно сделать? обычная `DoubleAnimation` вращает плавно.

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{StaticResource LoadingImage}" 
       Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotate"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation By="45" To="360" Storyboard.TargetName="rotate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                     Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

**UPD**

Под "не плавное" я имею ввиду мгновенное. То есть мне нужно, чтобы картинка вращалась по кругу непрерывно на 45 градусов за такт. Такт должен происходить мгновенно. То есть было 0 градусов, стало сразу 45. Через какое то время (например 0.2 секунды) еще +45 и тд...

Comment: Публикуйте в вопросе нерабочий код, который можно было бы подправить. Уважайте коллег.

Comment: @anme, держите. Просто скорее всего этот код имеет мало общего с решением и у кого то просто есть готовое. Поэтому не посчитал нужным выкладывать сразу

Comment: Смотрите на `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyframes`. Я напишу позже, если никто не успеет до меня.

Comment: @VladD, я наверное плохо с ним разобрался, но если я правильно понимаю, с `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyframes` мне придется каждый кадр прописывать отдельно для решения моей задачи. Или нет?

Comment: @iRumba: Хм, ну это да, придётся прописывать все кадры. А как иначе? Значение `KeyFrame` может быть любое по идее. Ну или надо думать не через `KeyFrame`, да.

Comment: @VladD, при таком раскладе мое решение проще. А что если мне понадобится на 10 градусов вращать? Я буду прописывать 36 кадров? :) Мне сейчас нужно только разделить 360 на нужное количество градусов и умножить на количество секунд в Duration и я получу требуемое фпс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна равномерная анимация, но по шагам. Это нестандартная анимация, поэтому обратимся к [Священному Источнику Знаний](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970564(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). В нём советуют создать свой `KeyFrame`. Этим и займёмся.

Мы унаследуемся от `DoubleKeyFrame`, так как мы анимируем свойство типа `double`. Нам нужно свойство, хранящее количество частей, положим его в стандартное `DependencyProperty` `NumberOfParts`. Ещё нам нужно реализовать абстрактные методы `CreateInstanceCore` (который просто клонирует наш объект, для него мы положим защищённый конструктор), и самое главное — метод `InterpolateValueCore`, в котором и будет наша логика вычисления значения.

```
class StepwiseDoubleKeyFrame : DoubleKeyFrame
{
    public StepwiseDoubleKeyFrame() { }

    protected StepwiseDoubleKeyFrame(double value, KeyTime keyTime, int numberOfParts) :
        base(value, keyTime)
    {
        NumberOfParts = numberOfParts;
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() =>
        new StepwiseDoubleKeyFrame(Value, KeyTime, NumberOfParts);

    protected override double InterpolateValueCore(double baseValue, double keyFrameProgress)
    {
        var fullDiff = Value - baseValue; // полный путь, который нужно пройти за целый фрейм
        // в keyFrameProgress текущее время фрейма, от 0 до 1.
        // считаем, в какую из частей мы сейчас попадаем.
        // например, если у нас 6 частей, а время между 4/6 и 5/6, по показываем 4/6
        var currentPart = Math.Floor(keyFrameProgress * NumberOfParts) / NumberOfParts;
        return baseValue + currentPart * fullDiff;
    }

    public int NumberOfParts
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberOfPartsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberOfPartsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfPartsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "NumberOfParts", typeof(int), typeof(StepwiseDoubleKeyFrame),
            new PropertyMetadata(4)); // по умолчанию 4 части
}
```

Теперь наш XAML выглядит так:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="..."
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="75">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotation"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Rotation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <local:StepwiseDoubleKeyFrame
                            KeyTime="100%" Value="360" NumberOfParts="8"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Результат:

[image: кручу-верчу, прогресс показать хочу]

Comment: Почти идеально. Почти, потому что тут все же нужно обрезать количество кадров в секунду. Ведь насколько я понимаю, `InterpolateValueCore` будет выполняться 60 раз в секунду. Так как плавная анимация тут не нужна, это лишние расходы ресурсов. Хотя это навскидку. Пока еще не добавил в проект.

Comment: @iRumba: Ну, поскольку результирующее значение угла будет одно и то же, думаю, что больших расходов не должно быть. Это ж только вычисление, а не поворот картинки.

Comment: Больших не будет. но в моем случае эта анимация будет крутиться в момент запроса к базе данных. База локальная SQLite, то есть выполняться запрос будет не на отдельный сервер и даже не в другом процессе. Наверное, я пересидел за старым железом, но таких вот напрасных расходов пытаюсь избегать, когда это не доставляет неудобств, конечно.

Comment: @iRumba: А вы попробуйте выключать видимость анимированного элемента. При этом картинка, понятно, обновляться не будет. А 60 изменений `double`'а в секунду на фоне чтения из базы — ноль.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент решил таким образом

```
<Storyboard Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="8">
    <DoubleAnimation By="45" To="360" IsAdditive="True" Storyboard.TargetName="rotate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                         Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

`Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="8"` означает 8 кадров в секунду. Анимация работает 1 секунду и за это время поворачивается 8 раз (от 0 до 360 по 45 градусов за раз).

Мне не очень нравится это решение, но пока лучше не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте [Easing function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751(v=vs.110).aspx) к Вашей анимации.

```
<DoubleAnimation By="45" To="360" Storyboard.TargetName="rotate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                 Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
</DoubleAnimation>
```

Comment: И что это? Просто скорость увеличивается.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос... добавил уточнение. Вы не правильно поняли что я имел ввиду.